# Passing variable from Java to Javascript using Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, html, thymeleaf

I have a java `Map<Country, List<Expr>> countryToExprMap` in the backend service.
In my web page rendered by Thymeleaf, I have a `Country` drop down to select Country, and a `Expr` drop down, where I only want `Expr`s mapped by the selected `Country` to be displayed.
To do that, I need to pass `countryToExprMap` from Java to Javascript so that I can know the eligible `Expr`s from a given `Country`, so as to build a `updateExprOptions` function to be called by the `Country` dropdown on "change" event. Something like:

```js
var exprDropDown = document.getElementById("exprs");

// Map from Java
var exprs = countryToExprMap[selectedCountry];

// Create options for the expr dropdown
for (var i = 0; i < exprs.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = exprs[i];
    option.text = exprs[i];
    exprDropDown.appendChild(option);
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's a way to pass the map variable from Java to JavaScript.  Any advice appreciated.

---

What I can think of is to stringify the map in Java,
set it as data-* attribute to a html element using Thymeleaf,
and at last deserialise the map in JavaScript to use it there.

Comment: _"Java to JSP"_ - do you mean JavaScript or JSP? They're different things

Comment: Sorry I meant JavaScript

Comment: Thymeleaf does this out of the box... have you read the Thymeleaf documentation on [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Metroids.

I was able to use Thymeleaf native way to solve it:

```js
// Access public static final Map COUNTRY_TO_EXPR_MAP in MyUtil.java
<script th:inline="javascript"
        th:with="countryToExprMap=${@my.package.MyUtil@COUNTRY_TO_EXPR_MAP}">
    const exprsMap = new Map(Object.entries([[${countryToExprMap}]]));
    ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (change ObjectMapper to any JSON stringifier you have)

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(countryToExprMap);
%>

<script>
const exprs = JSON.parse('<%=jsonStr%>');
document.getElementById("exprs")
  .innerHTML = `<option value="">Please select</option>
    ${exprs.map(val => `<option value="${val}">${val}</option>`).join("")}`;
</script>
```

If the JSON is not in the JSP, but can be delivered by your backend ass a file, then it is simpler:

```
fetch("yourListServiceReturningJSON")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(exprs => {
  document.getElementById("exprs")
    .innerHTML = `<option value="">Please select</option>
    ${exprs.map(val => `<option value="${val}">${val}</option>`).join("")}`;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this require manually copying `jsonStr` value to JavaScript? I'm trying to avoid any manual work. Sorry if this is a silly question as I'm quite new to JavaScript

Comment: Yes that is a bit silly - no you do not need more code than that. What I showed is the bit of the JSP that needs to include the `<script>const exprs = JSON.parse('<%=jsonStr%>');</script>` as minimum for the javascript to pick it up (for example if the rest of the script is in an external JS file) - if you do not want to use an objectmapper, then use whatever is current best practise in JAVA to stringify an array

Comment: Does this work if my java map is in the backend service classes, i.e., it's not a block of JSP code wrapped by `<%  %>` in the html

Comment: Thank you. I don’t really want to create a web service just to return the static map (when the map does change, there will be a new deployment). I’ve edited my question with a solution I can think of, by setting the map to html data-* attribute using Thymeleaf

Comment: Show how you do that. If it is something like `... data-list="{{ list }}"` then you can do the same in JS: `const exprs = {{ list }}`